# Spring - Execute code before controller's method is invoked

Tags: java, spring

Is there any annotation similar to `@PreAuthorize` or `@PreFilter` that I can use to run code before a method in the Controller is invoked?

I need to add info to the request context (specific to the method being called) to be then retrieved by the `ExceptionHandler`.

For example

```
@RestController
public MyController{

  @UnkwonwAnnotation("prepareContext(request.getAgentId())"){
  public ResponseEntity method1(RequestA requestA) {
    ...
  }

  @UnkwonwAnnotation("prepareContext(request.getUserName())"){
  public ResponseEntity method1(RequestB requestB) {
    ...
  }

}
```

I could actually just use `@PreAuthorize` but doesn't feel right

Comment: That's what a `HandlerInterceptor` is for. Implement the `preHandle` method and do your thing.

Answer (score 14):

You Can add interceptor for this

**Sample Interceptor**

```
public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse  response) {
    //Add Login here 
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyCustomInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In preHandle method, make sure to add a third parameter `Object handler`. Should be like this:
`public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)`

Answer (score 7):

Spring Aspect is also a good option to execute code before controller.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.test.myMethod(..)))")
    public void doSomethingBefore(JoinPoint jp) throws Exception {

        //code  
    }
}
```

Here `myMethod()` will execute before controller.

Answer (score 5):

A good option is to implement a custom filter that runs every time a request is received.

You need to extend "OncePerRequestFilter" and override the method "doFilterInternal":

```
public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Add attributes to request
        request.getSession().setAttribute("attrName", new String("myValue"));

        // Run the method requested by petition
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        //Do something after method runs if you need.
    }
}
```

You have to register the filter in Spring with FilterRegistrationBean. If you have Spring Security, you need add your filter after security filter.

Comment: The filter would not know what parameters the method  received

Comment: Yes, you have the request object in `oFilterInternal` method, here there are all parameters... you can work with all of them.
Just type
`request.getParameterNames() //for give all names.
request.getParameter("myParam") //for get the value of one parameter`

Comment: This way the filter would be cluttered with IF statements. I would like some annotation to go on the method that requires it

Comment: In that case the best option is use a interceptor. My solution its global, affects to all requests.

Comment: That still means the logic for every controller will be in one place

Comment: Yes, the logic you put in filter will run for requests to all controllers.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Sai Prateek answer, I'v created a custom annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface OperationContext {

  String clientId();

  String userId();

  String operation();
}
```

and a component to handle it:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class OperationContextAspect {

  @Before(value = "@annotation(operationContext)", argNames = "operationContext")
  public void preHandle(OperationContext operationContext) {

    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

    requestAttributes.setAttribute("operation", operationContext.operation, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    requestAttributes.setAttribute("clientId", operationContext.clientId(), RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    requestAttributes.setAttribute("userId", operationContext.userId(), RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);

  }
}
```

I then annotate the controller methods providing the required parameters:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @OperationContext(clientId = '#request.getClientId', userId = '#request.getUserId', operation = "OPERATION_A")
  public ResponseEntity aMethod(MyRequest request) {
    ...
  }
}
```